# An error occurred while sending mail (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: unknown protocol)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

configuration.yml

```
development:
   email_delivery:
     delivery_method: :smtp
     smtp_settings:
      #tls: true
       #enable_starttls_auto: true
       openssl_verify_mode: 'none'
       address: "domain name" 
       port: 25
       authentication: :login
       domain: 'mail domail name'
       user_name: 'mail id'
       password: 'pwd'
```

this code use to for the following error occurs

An error occurred while sending mail:

`SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: unknown protocol`

---

```
development:
email_delivery:
delivery_method: :smtp
smtp_settings:
tls: true
enable_starttls_auto: true
openssl_verify_mode: 'none'
address: "domain name" 
port: 587
authentication: :login
domain: 'mail domail name'
user_name: 'mail id'
password: 'pwd'
```

this code use to for the following error occurs

An error occurred while sending mail:

`No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2)`

---

```
development:
email_delivery:
delivery_method: :async_smtp
smtp_settings:
tls: true
enable_starttls_auto: true
openssl_verify_mode: 'none'
address: "domain name" 
port: 25
authentication: :login
domain: 'mail domail name'
user_name: 'mail id'
password: 'pwd'
```

### no error occurs but still not received mail on the user.

```
development:
email_delivery:
delivery_method: :smtp
smtp_settings:
tls: true
enable_starttls_auto: true
openssl_verify_mode: 'none'
address: "domain name" 
port: 25
authentication: :login
domain: 'mail domail name'
user_name: 'mail id'
password: 'pwd'
```

this code to use redmine version 2.2.3 to use work with fine. but version 2.3.0 to use not working now.

Comment: http://www.redmine.org/boards/1/topics/37402?r=37423 solve this problems

Comment: Its soo tiring to get one small thing working.  Have tried all possible combinations and suggested solutions.  Any expert who can help me out here?  I dont want to go through reinstall process.

Answer (score 11):

After fighting with this issues for several hours this is what I came up with (works for me)

```
email_delivery:
  delivery_method: smtp
  smtp_settings:
    openssl_verify_mode: none
    tls: false
    enable_starttls_auto: true
    address: smtp.xxx.xx
    port: 587
    domain: xxx.xx
    authentication: login
    user_name: "xxx@xxx.xx"
    password: xxx
```

make sure that the address matches the domain and it can be resolved